# С помощью чего делать поддержку разных экранов с помощью Layout или values?

Tags: android, android-layout

Как я понимаю есть два пути сделать поддержку mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi-xxhdpi экранов:

1. Делать под каждую плотность свой layout, со своими размерами и
   ложить его в соответствующую папку(layout-xhdpi etc)
2. Сделать один layout и сделать под каждую плотность свои
   values/dimens.xml

В первом случае будет браться шаблон более менее подходящий под текущий экран, а во втором будут браться значения размеров под соответствующий экран.

**Какой из этих способов лучше ?**

Если я что-то не так понял - поправте. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно понял. Только есть третий, идеальный вариант - делать резиновую разметку, которая будет выглядеть одинаково на всех экранах. Вес элемента в помощь. Разные layout`ы можно под планшет/телефон делать, но не под каждую плотность

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. А можно немного подробнее об резиновой разметки, пожалуйста?

Comment: @researcher не смогу сильно подробно ответить. На работе сразу научили так делать. Не успел столкнуться с проблемой разных плотностей. Используй FrameLayout`ы и LinearLayout`ы, вес и гравити элеметов